# Accessing IBM Tone Analyzer with PHP and CURL

Tags: php, curl, ibm-watson, tone-analyzer

I would like to access IBM Tone Analyzer through PHP using CURL, however, I keep getting authorization errors like shown below. The code I use is shown in the code section.

Although looking up numerous help pages and forums, I haven't found a suitable solution. Could someone please help me how to solve this?

Thanks a lot in advance.

With best regards!

This is the code i use:

```js
<?php

//print_r($_POST);

$ch = curl_init();

$file_path = "tone.json";
$url = "https://api.eu-gb.tone-analyzer.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/$BLACKENED$/v3/tone?$

$header_args = array(
   'Accept: application/json',
   'Content-Type: application/json',
   'Authorization: Basic apikey:$BLACKENED$'
);

curl_setopt_array($ch,array(CURLOPT_URL => $url, CURLOPT_HEADER => $header_args, CURLOPT_UPLOAD => true, CURLOPT_POST => true, CURLOPT_INFILE => $file_path));

$response = curl_exec($ch);

echo($response);

curl_close($ch);

?>
```

This is the error i get:

```html
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="IBM Watson Gateway(Log-in)" Content-Length: 164 Content-Type: application/json x-dp-watson-tran-id: $BLACKENED$ x-request-id: $BLACKENED$ x-global-transaction-id: $BLACKENED$ Server: watson-gateway X-EdgeConnect-MidMile-RTT: 0 X-EdgeConnect-Origin-MEX-Latency: 380 Date: Mon, 06 Dec 2021 21:46:28 GMT Connection: close {"code":401,"more_info":"https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/watson?topic=watson-authorization-error","error":"Unauthorized","trace":"$BLACKENED$"} 1
```

Comment: My guess - you will need to supply a better, more fully scoped set of parameters to support your curl request - specifically based around SSL connections. There are a few that should be used whenever you deal with an SSL protected endpoint - such as `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER`,`CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` and `CURLOPT_CAINFO` where you supply a valid `cacert.pem` file uri. Also - what is `CURLOPT_POS`??? have you truncated the values you send or is that a typo??

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius it's not likely an SSL problem. I originally thought the same until I realized that OP just posted the entire HTTP response with no line breaks. The actual reason, given in the body of the response at the end, is an authentication error.

Comment: The response tells you that it is an authentication error, and even gives you a link to the relevant docs including troubleshooting. https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/watson?topic=watson-authorization-error

Comment: To @ProfessorAbronsius: Thanks for your response. I missed something from my code which i edited now. I do not get an cacert.pem file, but i tried the ssl options. However, this doesn't helped in any way. I see that it is an authentication error, but how can i solve this?

Comment: To @Sammitch: Thanks, I've read this documentation, but it didn't help me so far. You have some advice on how to solve this?